# How to fetch data from Firestore and display them in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in Flutter and firestore. I have a collection in firestore with following order:
event->'a user specific id'->post->'a post id->'post details'. you can see here[Firestore1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSzUt.png) and here[Firestore2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxW9J.png)

When I try to fetch the 'postdetails', only thing I get is 'Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot',see here[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boF23.png)

What i tried:

```
 getEvents() async {
setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
});

DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await eventref
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('post')
    //.orderBy('Date', descending: true)
    .doc()
    .get();

print('Snapshot : ${snapshot}');
 return snapshot;
// setState(() {
//   _isLoading = false;

//   print(event);
// });
```

}

I have also made a model for events. See here[Event Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS4gS.png)

I want to fetch data and display them as card.
Any help?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Snapshot : ${snapshot.data()["Date"]}');
```

Using `data()` you can access the fields value.

Comment: it gave error: E/flutter (22875): Tried calling: []("Date")
E/flutter (22875): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (22875): #1      _TimelineState.getEvents

Comment: try `snapshot.data()`

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot.get("field_name")
```

You need to  ask flutter to retrieve the fields inside the document snapshot.

Will need a more detailed order of your firestore collection and document to provide the exact code. You may follow the sample below:

**On firestore:**

```
-Collection: "users"
---Document: "userId"
-------Field: "username"
-------Field: "birthdate"
```

**Code:**

```
DocumentSnapshot doc =await _firestore.collection("users").doc(userId).get();
print(doc.get('username'));
print(doc.get('birthdate'));
```